# xlsxWriter URL formatting issue

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am iterating through a list of links and writing them into an Excel worksheet. However the links are not showing in the Excel default mode which is blue underlined font. I added the third line of code below which makes the links appear blue and underlined, however the third line formatting overrides (as it should) the formatting of the `set_align('vcenter')`. What can I do (without using font colors formatting) to make it work?

```
link_format = workbook.add_format()
link_format.set_align('vcenter')
link_format = workbook.get_default_url_format()   

row = 1
column = 1

# iterating through all_links_array list
for item in all_links_array:
    worksheet.write(row, column, item, link_format)
    row += 1
```

Comment: Try putting the `link_format.set_align('vcenter')` after the what is currently the third line. You can all delete the first line since what follows effectively ignores it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great. My alternative solution (that also worked) was to change the links' fonts to blue and underline them. However your suggestion was the one that I was looking for. Thanks again.